# Prevent bootstrap dropdown from closing on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I want to implement bootstrap dropdown with input type=text instead of button.
Although I am able to do so with following code but not able to prevent this dropdown from closing on click event.

```
 <div class="dropdown">
   <div class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">
      <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" >
      <div ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
        <a href="" style="margin-left:15px;">Select All</a><a href="" style="margin-left:20px;">Unselect All</a>
          <ul >
              <li ng-repeat="test in testArr "ng-click="doSomething(this)">{{test.name}}</li>
          </ul>
      </div>

  </div>
```

Tried many answers but could not help with any

Comment: Do you like auto complete option for a textbox?

Comment: I just want to make list in dropdown to be multiselect instead of single select

Comment: @Ashish_B  check out the angular multiselect directive.  http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main

Comment: Most likely need to bind to the textbox and `stopPropagation` so Bootstrap doesn't detect it as an out-of-context click.